# DetailView не открывается при парсинге

Tags: xcode, парсер, ios, objective-c, rss

Скачал вот такой [симпатичный парсер](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) и решил его перенести на площадку поновее, перенёс вроде всё, но теперь не работает Detail. Чтобы не быть голословным, [вот мой проект](http://cl.ly/280B04260b3L?_ga=1.128603530.701167339.1426154549). Т.е. подскажите, как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на новость открывалось её подробное описание? Я так понимаю, дело во "связях", т.е. в старом проекте есть такая связка view - file's owner, в новом проекте я не смог додумать, как её сделать, причина только в этом?

[image]
[image]

Comment:  >вот мой проект

rar? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел

[image]

У вас в этот момент navigationController равен nil.

Нужно поменять тип сигвея с кнопки, указать show вместо модального.

И добавить UINavigationController в начало сториборда:

[image]

И тогда получится вот так:

[image]

Comment: подскажите, пож-та, как это исправить?

Comment: добавил к ответу решение

Comment: @tragvar да, спасибо, заработало, только у меня получилось, как в моём вопросе, это очень плохо? (т.к. View Controller я планирую сделать как меню)

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов не плохо, можно и так. Только вы тогда не вернетесь на ViewController с кнопкой.

Comment: @tragvar подскажите, а как переделать, как у вас, просто я когда создаю Navigation controller, автоматически создаётся связка с root view controller, а как разорвать эту связку и сделать, как у вас?
Ps таки вы не правы, без проблем поставил кнопку возвращения назад, картинка в вопросе

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов кнопка назад появится автоматически, если сделать как у меня. 

Добавляете на сториборд новый Navigation controller, удаляете рутовский контроллер который вместе с ним появился, у вас остается чистый Navigation controller. Зажав Ctrl наводим мышь на Navigation controller, зажимаем ЛКМ и тянем на наш ViewController, выбираем связь с типом "root view controller". Перетягиваем стартовую стрелку с ViewController, который с кнопкой, на Navigation. Удаляем сигвей с ViewController на RootViewController, добавляем новый с типом "Show" (НЕ "present modal"!!). Вроде все. )